# Influxdb: Query for distinct values

Tags: iot, sensors, influxdb

First: I am aware of the distinct() function, but that's not what I want.

My problem: Imagine a series with sensor readings that barely change like e.g:

`[2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 5, 5, 2]`

In my application this series is very long (thousands of entries) and I would like to visualize it in a Diagram (on Android, but that doesn't matter).

What I'd like to achieve:

I would like to get the values, where the series changes e.g:

`[2,       3,       4,             3,    5,    2]`

of course with their respective timestamps and tags.

With the distinct() function the result would look like this:

`[2,       3,       4,                   5,     ]`

Thanks!